# How to manipulate context data in a view with a ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to manipulate context data using DetailView before it is rendered to the template. Changing attributes on the main model (Collection) works fine, but changing attributes on the second table (Song) doesn't change anything.

Models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Collection(models.Model):
    collection_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    artist_display_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    songs = models.ManyToManyField('Song', through='CollectionSong')

class CollectionSong(models.Model):
    collection = models.ForeignKey('Collection')
    song = models.ForeignKey('Song')
    track_number = models.IntegerField()
    volume_number = models.IntegerField()

class Song(models.Model):
    song_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    artist_display_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    track_length = models.IntegerField()
```

Views.py

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from .models import Collection

class AlbumView(DetailView):
    model = Collection
    template_name = 'album.html'
    context_object_name = 'collection'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AlbumView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['collection'].name = "YYY" # This works

        for song in context['collection'].songs.all():
            song.name = "XXX" # This does not work

        return context
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because queryset each time will return fresh data from database (it's cached under the hood but we can assume that is fresh) so it won't return your changed data until you save it into database.

Comment: Thanks. What's the best way to change data from the second model without saving to the database?

Comment: If you need to do it - reconsider your design. I don't think there is actual need for that. But if you really need it - you must ensure to pass exact same object that you've modified.